# Using for loops to define global variables

Tags: javascript

I am defining some global arrays at the top of my JS file. There are  for loops to populate the arrays. I have done very similar things that have worked but for some reason, this is having issues. The first for loop runs through only one time and the code below that never gets ran.

```
var group = 'a';
var RoofVar = 1;
var TrimVar = 1;
var BBVar = 1;
var imageArrayGroup0 = [];
var floatingButtonArrayGroup0 = [];
var labelArrayGroup0 = [];
for (a = 1; a < 3; a++) {
    labelArrayGroup0[a] = document.createElement("Label");
    labelArrayGroup0[a].type = "Label";
    floatingButtonArrayGroup0[a] = document.getElementById('floatingButton0' + (100 + a));
    floatingButtonArrayGroup0[a].style.textAlign = "center";
    floatingButtonArrayGroup0[a].style.paddingTop = "5px";
    labelArrayGroup0[a] = document.getElementById('floatingButton0' + (100 + x));
}

var imageArray0 = [];
var floatingButtonArray0 = [];
var labelArray0 = [];
for (b = 1; b < 5; b++) {
    imageArray0[b] = document.createElement("img");
    imageArray0[b].type = "image";
    floatingButtonArray0[b] = document.getElementById('floatingButton0' + (b));
    floatingButtonArray0[b].style.paddingLeft = "15px";
    floatingButtonArray0[b].style.paddingTop = "5px";
    labelArray0[b] = document.getElementById('floatingButton0' + b);
}

var imageArray1 = [];
var floatingButtonArray1 = [];
var labelArray1 = [];
for (c = 1; c < 3; c++) {
    imageArray1[c] = document.createElement("img");
    imageArray1[c].type = "image";
    floatingButtonArray1[c] = document.getElementById('floatingButton1' + (c));
    floatingButtonArray1[c].style.paddingLeft = "15px";
    floatingButtonArray1[c].style.paddingTop = "5px";
    labelArray1[c] = document.getElementById('floatingButton1' + c);
}
```

Comment: What's in the JS console? Also, several "I don't even..."

Comment: What is this I don’t even ....

Comment: Should `'floatingButton0' + (100 + x)` (last line, first loop) be `'floatingButton0' + (100 + a)`? Since `x` is undefined, an error would be thrown at that point, ending the script. Again, check your Javascript console, first and always.

Comment: From Webmasters StackExchange: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: Thanks @PaulRoub. That was the answer. I forgot to switch out the x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have other issues than just "`(100 + x)` instead of `(100 + a)`.

First, arrays in JavaScript are "zero-based" but your loops start at 1.
This means you're putting things in but leaving spot '0' undefined, which will probably break things later.

Next. at the beginning of the loop you set `labelArrayGroup0[a]` to a new blank label, but you never do anything to put it on the page. At the end the loop, you overwrite `labelArrayGroup0[a]` to a `floatingButton` element you pull from the page.

In fact, you do this in every loop - the last line resets the value of the 1st line. 
It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Presumably you intend to append `labelArrayGroup0[a]` to the page instead?

Also, in the middle, you set `floatingButtonArrayGroup0[a] = document.getElementById('floatingButton0' + (100 + a));` which is the same element you grab in the last line of the loop...

Answer (score 0):

Paul had my answer.  I forgot to switch out the "x" for an "a".